# moving parent level element to the looping group of child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Tim - thank you! What you provided based on my input certainly does work!
I however fell the victim of my own ego. My initial input was a sctructurally scaled down version of my actual xml file and I thought I would be able to apply the concept of your help and get what I need in the end... Guess what? Even though the change is minor, I still cannot. Some good number of variations/adjustments for code, including using full path in "copy-of select=", just will not put the KEY under the DOCUMENT. The only way it works is when I use "xsl:copy-of select="//KEY" /".

The other issue I ran into is how to ensure that only the "KEY" that the "Document" is under, gets copied to under that "Document"... With the "as is" code, all  elements in XML get copied to each of the  nodes (again, only when I'm using the "//" operator).

Please help.

Here's my NOT scaled down structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Root>
        <Level1>
                <KEY><![CDATA[keyword1]]></KEY>
                <Documents> 
                            <Document>
                                    <TYPE>type1</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string11]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                            <Document>
                                    <TYPE>type2</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string12]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                            <Document>
                                    <TYPE>type3</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string13]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                </Documents>
        </Level1>
        <Level1>
                <KEY><![CDATA[keyword2]]></KEY>
                <Documents> 
                            <Document>
                                    <TYPE>type1</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string21]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                            <Document>
                                    <TYPE>type2</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string22]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                            <Document>
                                    <TYPE>type3</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string23]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                </Documents>
        </Level1>
</Root>
```

My desired result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Root>
        <Level1>
                <Documents> 
                            <Document>
                                    <KEY><![CDATA[keyword1]]></KEY>
                                    <TYPE>type1</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string11]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                            <Document>
                                    <KEY><![CDATA[keyword1]]></KEY>
                                    <TYPE>type2</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string12]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                            <Document>
                                    <KEY><![CDATA[keyword1]]></KEY>
                                    <TYPE>type3</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string13]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                </Documents>
        </Level1>
        <Level1>
                <Documents> 
                            <Document>
                                    <KEY><![CDATA[keyword2]]></KEY>
                                    <TYPE>type1</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string21]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                            <Document>
                                    <KEY><![CDATA[keyword2]]></KEY>
                                    <TYPE>type2</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string22]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                            <Document>
                                    <KEY><![CDATA[keyword2]]></KEY>
                                    <TYPE>type3</TYPE>
                                    <IMAGE><![CDATA[string23]]></IMAGE>
                            </Document>
                </Documents>
        </Level1>
</Root>
```

Sorry... And, again, thank you.

Comment: why don't you have anything as not working yet? what have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to read up on the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which looks like this

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will copy all the nodes to the output documents without change. This means you then only need to write templates for the things you do need to change.

You also shouldn't really think of this of moving an element, but of two changes; Removing the **KEY** element from under the **Documents** element, and then adding a new **KEY** element (that is a copy of the existing one) under the **Document**.

Removing the **KEY** element is straight-forward. Just match it, and do nothing

```
<xsl:template match="KEY" />
```

Adding a new element under the **Document** element, is also straight forward. You need a template that matches the **Document** element, which will be similar to the identity template, but with an extra copy, to copy the **KEY** node from the parent.

```
<xsl:template match="Document">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="../KEY" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

So, you copy the **Document** element, copy across attributes (if any), copy the **KEY** from the parent, and then continue processing child nodes.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="KEY" />

   <xsl:template match="Document">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="../KEY" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: As an alternative, if the **KEY** is not a child of the parent node, but can at any depth, try replacing the copy statement with this instead

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::*[KEY]/KEY" />
```

This should cope with the **document** element being at any level.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally.... Here's the Tim's original xsl (with a tiny adjustment),  that gives me the desired result. Tim - thanks again. XSLT is outside of my area of expertise. I'm just trying to use it the "preparation" tool:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
```

```
<xsl:template match="KEY" />

<xsl:template match="Document">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="../../KEY" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've made an edit to my original answer to cope with **Document** elements being nested to deeper levels, and so will work with your original XML and your latest example.